# Print/extract changelog.md specific sections

Tags: shell, parsing, sh, changelog

I need to extract/print specific sections using a shell script for the following changelog file in markdown:

```
    # Changelog
    All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

    The format is based on [Keep a Changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/),
    and this project adheres to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html).

    ## [Unreleased]

    ## [4.0.75 - 507] - 2019-06-24

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 506] - 2019-06-21

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 505] - 2019-06-17

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text
    - Changelog text
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 504] - 2019-06-11

    ### Added
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.74 - 503] - 2019-05-29

    ### Added
    - Changelog text
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.73 - 502] - 2019-05-22
```

Examples of what I would like to achieve:

Input section `4.0.75 - 507`
Desired output:

```
    ## [4.0.75 - 507] - 2019-06-24

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text
```

Input section `4.0.75`
Desired output:

```
    ## [4.0.75 - 507] - 2019-06-24

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 506] - 2019-06-21

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 505] - 2019-06-17

    ### Fixed
    - Changelog text
    - Changelog text
    - Changelog text

    ## [4.0.75 - 504] - 2019-06-11

    ### Added
    - Changelog text
```

What would be the best solution using a shell script ? I tried `awk` without any success.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your blank lines are indeed blank (eg, there's no whitespace), you could do:

```
awk 's{ print ""; print}; $0~v {print; s=1; next}; s=0' RS= v=4.0.74 input
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Works pretty well with the version number but using `4.0.75 - 507` didn't work. Should I escape some characters?

Comment: Did you quote the string properly when passing it to awk:  eg: `v="4.0.75 - 507"`

Comment: If not, awk will take `-` and `507` as input file names.

Comment: Quoting the variable resolved my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: So I have a question with your solution. If I have two tags`## [2.02.16] - 2023-01-10` and  `## [2.01.61] - 2022-02-16` and I search for just '2.02.16`, I will get both of those results back. Is there a way to prevent the tag search from also hitting the date numbers?

Comment: `v` can be an arbitrary regex, so you can match any way you like.  Getting the escaping right can be a bit tricky, but you could match the full tag with something like `awk 's{ print ""; print}; $0~v {print; s=1; next}; s=0' RS= v='^## \\[2.02.16\\] - 2023-01-10$' input`